# How do I make featured images retreived by the_post_thumbnail() responsive?

Tags: responsive

I am trying to make the featured images retrieved by the_post_thumbnai() in the loop responsive, but can't seem to find a simplified solution.

The logic I want to implement is something like this:

```
If the screen size is less or equal to 728px
the_post_thumbnai('thumbnail') //Display the thumbnail size image 
Else 
the_post_thumbnai() //display the original size image
```

Can anyone suggest how I can do this without any plugins?

I am not a php expert, so please go easy on the lingo.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have time to add a detailed answer right now, but you can utilise Wordpress' built in srcset generation by running the img tag through the_content filter - there's a bit of set up to it to make sure it'll work, esp. making sure the right class is on the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't combine PHP and CSS in this way, as PHP is server-side and does not know client screen width, while CSS is client-side and does not know server functions. Instead, you could output both image sizes and then use CSS to show/hide them. eg:

```
<div class="image-thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></div>
<div class="image-fullsize"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?></div>
```

and CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 728px) {
    .image-thumbnail {display: block;}
    .image-fullsize {display: none;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 729px) {
    .image-thumbnail {display: none;}
    .image-fullsize {display: block;}
}
```

An alternative approach would be to output the one full size image and use CSS to adjust the width depending on the client screen width instead.

```
<div class="image-fullsize"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?></div>
```

with CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 728px) {
   .image-fullsize img {width: 200px; height:auto;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 729px) {
   .image-fullsize img {width: 100%; height:auto;}
}
```

The difference being with the first method the *cropped* thumbnail will be displayed but with the second the *scaled* full size image will be displayed for the thumbnail (and you can add more breakpoints later.)

Comment: Thank you very much.  A brilliantly simple - yet effective - solution.  Worked like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

The PHP template that generates the HTML output does not know the screen size.  You can use [`img srcset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) in your template but you won't have 100% browser compatibility.  Or, just use CSS to adjust the image size.